# Html data cell shrinks with form-control select2 laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form with different inputs. A section of the form is as shown below:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="title[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="activity_type[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
    <td><select class='form-control select2' name='media_format'>
            @foreach ($media_format as $format)
                <option value="{{$format}}" selected="">{{$format}}</option>
            @endforeach</select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="learning_mode[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
    <td><select class='form-control select2' name='difficulty_level'>
        @foreach ($difficulty_level as $level)
            <option value="{{$level}}" selected="">{{$level}}</option>
        @endforeach</select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="expected_learning_time_in_minutes[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

The cells are distributed evenly when all the input types where `text`.
[image]
When I add a drop-down menu, I don't know why the cells for the drop-down shrink in proportion to other cells.
[image]

Comment: I suppose a screenshot of your problem will do better than text explanation.

Comment: I've added screenshots @u_mulder.

Comment: I suppose `select` by default uses __width__ of it's longest value in `options`. You should explicitly set width of `td` with `select`s.

Comment: That works, thanks @u_mulder. Is there no other way, however, to automatically make all equal without having to explicitly define widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `u_mulder`'s comment, one solution is to explicitly set the width of the cell like:

```
<tr>
<td width="5%"><input type="text" . . . . </td>
<td width="14%"><select class='form-control select2' . . . . </td>
```

Any `text` cell which is not set expands according to the space left.